# Compiling C programs on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, c

I'm an absolute beginner at writing programs in C, and I'm having difficulty compiling a simple program. Here's my code:

```
/* This code is a .c file that prints out the words hello, world. */

# include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World! \n");
}
```

Here's the error I get when compiling:

```
Ubuntu:~/Desktop/cFiles$ gcc -Wall hello.c -o hello.out -lmls 
hello.c:5:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wreturn-type]
hello.c: In function ‘main’:
hello.c:7:3: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘print’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
hello.c:8:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type] /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmls
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can anyone help?

Comment: I have corrected your code formatting for you.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please remember to [format your post properly](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help). This assures you have a high quality questions, which will receive the high quality answers it deserves! Thanks and good luck!

Comment: The code is fine, your compile command is the problem, just gcc hello.c will produce no errors, and a working a.out executable.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have an unwanted `space` between `#` and `include`:

```
# include <stdio.h>
```

Make that

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

and compile.
That should solve it for you.

Comment: The space is not the problem, it compiles fine with it, and removing it does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your code is not compiling is because of the -lmls at the end of the line.  This is looking for a library called "mls".  (Perhaps you are going to be coding with [libmls for Maximum Length Sequence](http://libmls0.sourceforge.net/) later?)

Compile with

```
Ubuntu:~/Desktop/cFiles$ gcc -Wall hello.c -o hello.out
```

The rest of your output is warnings.  Most of them do not match the code which you provided.  To remove the compiler warnings:

1. You have already fixed "return type defaults to ‘int’" in the code that you provided (by adding int as the return type of main).
2. You have already fixed the "implicit declaration of function ‘print’" by adding the #include.
3. To remove "control reaches end of non-void function" warning add return(0); to the end of the main function.